# "for" versus "to", indicating who/what the recipient is

Tags: prepositions

Consider:

> The European Union is working on Solvency II which assigns capital **for** a wider set
>   of risks than Solvency I.
>
> One approach to overcoming this problem is for regulators themselves to provide the scenarios. This creates a lot of additional work **for** regulators, but it is obviously attractive for them to use the same set of scenarios for all banks.
>
> If regulators see many banks taking positions with similar risks, they could insist that all banks consider a particular set of scenarios that gave rise to adverse results **for** the positions.
>
> The problem **for** both senior management and the risk management group is that they have two separate reports on their desks concerning what could go wrong.

I think these "for" here fits the 1st definition (used to show who is intended to have or use something or where something is intended to be put) in OALD. I am not sure if it is the same usage as in "get/buy/bring sth for sb", which indicates sb is the recipient of sth.

However, I wonder why sometimes **to** is used instead as in "give/sing/explain sth to sb". Here **to** also indicates sb is the recipient of sth. Here **to** introduces an indirect object.

If I replaced "for" with "to" in my examples above, would it bring any difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I saw your other question first.  I'll take a shot at writing these sentences without the word "for" as well (and avoid "to" while I'm at it):

> The European Union is working on Solvency II which assigns capital **that will serve the purpose of** a wider set
>   of risks than Solvency I.
>
> One approach to overcoming this problem is for regulators themselves to provide the scenarios. This creates a lot of additional work **that** regulators **must do**, but it is obviously attractive for them to use the same set of scenarios for all banks.
>
> If regulators see many banks taking positions with similar risks, they could insist that all banks consider a particular set of scenarios that **caused** the positions **to have** adverse results.
>
> The problem **concerning** both senior management and the risk management group is that they have two separate reports on their desks concerning what could go wrong.

So, if you replaced "for" with "to" in your examples above, would there be any difference?  Yes, a small one.  To means roughly "directed at", whereas for means roughly "on behalf of".

So, if I say "Explain that to me" I'm asking you to give me the explanation.  If I say "Explain that for me" I might be asking you to give me the explanation as a favor ("do something for me" means do it because I would like you to, so do it as a favor), and I might also be asking you to give someone else the explanation instead of explaining it myself.